# How to setting code formatting for flutter in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

So i want to setting my code formatting for flutter in android studio
[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwPPR.png)

but when i do Ctrl+Alt+L it becomes [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkfL2.png)

Comment: Try to add a comma(",") after each component. And then try this shortcut key

Answer (score 1):

To make the code reformat as you want it to, you need to add a comma `,` at the end of all properties. Example:

```dart
Container(
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
)
```

Without the last comma, you get this:

```dart
Container(width: 10, height: 10)
```